# If frame named "xyz" exists, then switch to that frame

Tags: emacs, elisp

Could someone please give me hand with a function that detects whether a frame named "xyz" exists, and if so, then switch to that frame.  I'm using `frame-cmds` to give each frame a user-defined name:  http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/frame-cmds.el

I would imagine it is similar to a buffer, but I'm not finding anything on Google.  Here is the buffer function:

```
(defun buffer-exists (bufname)
    (not (eq nil (get-buffer bufname))))

(defun lawlist-switch-to-buffer-xyz ()
(interactive)
    (if (buffer-exists "xyz")
        (switch-to-buffer "xyz") ))
```

Here is a semi-related post:  https://superuser.com/questions/358037/emacsclient-create-a-frame-if-a-frame-does-not-exist

---

**EDIT** (September 15, 2014):  Modified the function `ido-switch-frame` to make `frame-to` a let-bound variable, and removed the `message`.  Removed previous edits as the functions `get-a-frame` and `get-frame-name` written by Drew Adams are sufficient when used in conjunction with `select-frame-set-input-focus` -- see his answer below.

```lisp
(defun ido-switch-frame ()
(interactive)
  (when (not (minibufferp))
    (let* (
        (frames (frame-list))
        (frame-to (ido-completing-read "Select Frame:  "
          (mapcar (lambda (frame) (frame-parameter frame 'name)) frames))))
      (catch 'break
        (while frames
          (let ((frame (car frames)))
            (if (equal (frame-parameter frame 'name) frame-to)
              (throw 'break (select-frame-set-input-focus frame))
              (setq frames (cdr frames)))))))))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be more elegant solutions but this gets the job done:

```
(defun switch-to-frame (frame-name)
  (interactive "sFrame name:")
  (let ((frames (frame-list)))
    (catch 'break
      (while frames
        (let ((frame (car frames)))
          (if (equal (frame-parameter frame 'name) frame-name)
              (throw 'break (select-frame-set-input-focus frame))
            (setq frames (cdr frames))))))))
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this useful function.  I tried setting up a `(message "%s" frames)` | `(message "%s" frame-list)`, but got error messages.  `frame-list` is not interactive and doesn't come up as a function when word-searching the *.el Emacs source files.  Is there any way to return a printed display list of all frame names, to help me decide which frame I want to switch to?

Comment: Okay, one step closer -- `(message "%s" frames)` is not throwing an error message -- it actually returns a long string containing each of the frame names.  Now I just need to weed out the short frame names from the long string -- `(#<frame FRAME-NAME 0x105083fc0>`

Comment: @lawlist Entering responses as separate comments so they're not in one giant unreadable paragraph: 1) `frame-list` is a function, not a variable, which is why `(message %s frame-list)` printed an error about it not being a variable (in the future, when you get an error message, please copy it here; it's useful information). You need `(message %s (frame-list))` to see the result of calling it.

Comment: @lawlist 2) The reason you didn't see `frame-list` in the Emacs lisp source is that it's implemented in C. You can get information about any function (including where it's implemented) by `C-h f`, e.g., `C-h f frame-list`.

Comment: @lawlist 3) `(frame-list)` returns a list of frame objects. Your `message` shows a printed representation of each frame object, which is not the same as its name. To get the name of `frame`, use `(frame-parameter frame 'name)`. To get the name of every frame, you can use `(mapcar (lambda (frame) (frame-parameter frame 'name)) (frame-list))`.

Comment: AWESOME LEARNING EXPERIENCE !!!!  Thank you very much -- greatly appreciated ! :)

Answer (score 1):

1. Wrt your request for "a function that detects whether a frame named "xyz" exists": You already have that, since you say you are using [frame-cmds.el](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/frame-cmds.el), which requires [frame-fns.el](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/frame-fns.el) --- Function `get-a-frame` does just that.
2. **[Icicles](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles)** provides [multi-command](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Multi-Commands#multi-command) [`icicle-select-frame`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Tripping), which lets you choose frames by name using completion.

Comment: Thank you for the post -- I'll check them out in the next few days -- greatly appreciated!